# I am getting this error when try to build the apk through Android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jacoco, gradlew, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am getting this error when trying to build the `apk` through Android studio. Here is the exception I've got:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':My_Service:transformClassesWithJacocoForDebug'.
    > There was a failure while executing work items
       > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JacocoTransform$JacocoWorkerAction
```

Whereas, there is ***not*** such error when I do build through command window using command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease assembleReleaseUnsigned
```

Comment: Without information about you system its really hard to provide help.

Comment: I am running it on ubuntu.

Comment: Version ? Version of Java ... etc, so much more info to be provided

Comment: Android-studio version 3.0.1 java-openjdk version "1.8.0_162" gradle -version 4.1

Comment: The issue is coming once the gradle version is updated from 3.0.0 to 3.1.4

Comment: @SangameshItagi did you find any solution to it ??

Answer (score 0):

I've created an ImageAsserts of arrow icon where I've removed all variants of dpi. xml file except `any-dpi.xml` which resulted into this mentioned exception. After removing this exception got resolved.